# how do I display two divs side by side in html?

Tags: html, css

Please check the snippet below

```
<div style="margin-right: 20%;text-align: justify;float: left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porttitor dapibus ipsum ut efficitur. Aliquam feugiat nec sem dapibus blandit. Nam non faucibus urna, at pulvinar nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut eget aliquet diam.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 80%;float:right;">
        <a href="mailto:email@example.com"
           rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"
           target="_blank">Email@example.com</a><br>(408) 553-3222<br>Boston
    </div>
```

I don't know why it wouldn't display the content side by side?
Same code is there at https://jsfiddle.net/atrwq86b/

Comment: both divs needs width first element's text expanding divs width

Comment: I've put together seven distinct methods to place two elements next to each other: https://boldewyn.github.io/grid-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the margins and u can use `width` and float to align them side by side.

See the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/atrwq86b/1/)

```
<div style="width: 65%; text-align: justify; float: left">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porttitor dapibus ipsum ut efficitur. Aliquam feugiat nec sem dapibus blandit. Nam non faucibus urna, at pulvinar nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut eget aliquet diam.
 </div>
            <div style="width: 30%; float:right;">
                <a href="mailto:email@example.com"
                   rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"
                   target="_blank">Email@example.com</a><br>(408) 553-3222<br>Boston
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the margins and use `display:inline-block` and add some width on the containers.

```
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 30%; text-align: justify;float: left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porttitor dapibus ipsum ut efficitur. Aliquam feugiat nec sem dapibus blandit. Nam non faucibus urna, at pulvinar nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut eget aliquet diam.
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;float:right;">
            <a href="mailto:email@example.com"
               rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"
               target="_blank">Email@example.com</a><br>(408) 553-3222<br>Boston
        </div>
```

Your fiddle updated:
https://jsfiddle.net/atrwq86b/2/

Comment: your code worked, even when I removed **display: inline-block**.

Answer (score 1):

To display the content side by side, remove the ‘margin-right/margin-left’ and ‘float’ style of the div and apply ‘width’ and only ‘margin’ as well as 'display : inline-block' style to both div.
The code has been given below:

```
<div style="width: 65%; margin:1%; display:inline-block; text-align: justify; ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porttitor dapibus ipsum ut efficitur. Aliquam feugiat nec sem dapibus blandit. Nam non faucibus urna, at pulvinar nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut eget aliquet diam.
    </div>
    <div style="width: 30%; margin:1%; display:inline-block;">
        <a href="mailto:email@example.com"
           rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"
           target="_blank">Email@example.com</a><br>(408) 553-3222<br>Boston
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Float both the div's `left` and give the left one a fixed width (as the long text was making it run too far off the page to see any change. Also remove the percentage margins. See updated code:

```
<div style="text-align: justify;width:100px; float: left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porttitor dapibus ipsum ut efficitur. Aliquam feugiat nec sem dapibus blandit. Nam non faucibus urna, at pulvinar nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut eget aliquet diam.
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <a href="mailto:email@example.com"
           rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"
           target="_blank">Email@example.com</a><br>(408) 553-3222<br>Boston
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `width` instead `margin` and read something about how `margin` property works.

```html
<div style="width: 80%;text-align: justify;float: left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porttitor dapibus ipsum ut efficitur. Aliquam feugiat nec sem dapibus blandit. Nam non faucibus urna, at pulvinar nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut eget aliquet diam.
        </div>
        <div style="width: 20%;float:right;">
            <a href="mailto:email@example.com"
               rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"
               target="_blank">Email@example.com</a><br>(408) 553-3222<br>Boston
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<div style="width: 75%;text-align: justify;display:inline-block; vertical-align: text-top;">Fisrt DIV</div>
        <div style="width: 20%;display:inline-block; vertical-align: text-top;">Second DIV</div>
```